# Fetching other main copy's update in forked copy on github

Tags: git, github

I have created a project on github. The project is **forked** by my friend.
Then i have made changes to my local branch, committed them, push to my remote. Now question is that how can my friend's **remote will get changes from my remote** to his remote? so that later he can fetch to his local and make changes to local, push to his remote and again my remote will get his changes. How can i do this?

Question might sound to be dumb but i am new to Git and Git-Hub.
You can suggest good guide for collaborative software development using git and github.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend should add your repo as one of his remote's.
He will probably already have his repo as origin if he cloned from the github address of his fork.
Now he needs to do something like (he may choose a different name than upstream):

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/adambure21/project_name.git
```

And then he'll be able to do fetch from it:

```
git fetch upstream master #fetch master from upstream into upstream/master
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer, i found it on githubs web site under help.

1. When my friend fork, my repository, he must clone his remote to local. (Here my friends remote contains forked version of my repository.)
2. After cloning, my friend shall make changes to his local and commit then he will push local changes to his remote.
3. Now, in order to reflect my friends changes from his remote to my remote, he has to make pull request.
4. When he is done with pull request, i am having a notification in my notification section my my git hub account.(This section is near to your profile name at right corner having HDD like icon.)
5. Now, I have to respond to his pull request and merge both repositories. This is GUI based activity and can be done from notification section of your profile. I last stage it asks for confirmation of merge.
6. After this, do refresh page, latest changes made by him will be there in your remote.